# I want the properties of __list__?

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class successors that contains a list of successors. [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
node_successors = Successors()
```

When the class is assigned to a variable, for example:

```
neigbour = node_successors
```

I want neighbour to be set to the list I have stored within the class (without having to call `get_successor_list()` for example)

Similar to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "This class can be used as a string now"
```

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? I can't understand it.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear

Comment: No, `__str__` doesn't make the variable "magically" convertible to a string, you need to apply `str` on it anyway.

Comment: ["Explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Do you actually need a `list` or do you just want the `Successors` object to be iterable?

Comment: If I'm reading this properly... you want `neighbour = node_successors` to magically somehow have `neighbour` be set to an attribute of the instance? No - you can't do that... either you call `get_sucessor_list()` on the object to return your list, or you access the attribute directly on the instance...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe will be useful for you to read this section in Python3 reference docs: [Emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)

With your example it seems you want to get a list from your object (not the properties), you would do:

- If you want to extract a list from your object, you can implement [the iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) (`__iter__()`). Then you can do `list(yourInstance)`
- Alternatively you can implement [bound indexing](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) (`__len__()` and `__getitem__()`) either.
- `neighbour = node_successors.get_successor_list()` if this function returns a list.

Answer (score -1):

you can make the list inside the class global.

```
class SomeClass:

    global some_list
    some_list = []

some_list.append('x')

print(some_list)
```